# Root-mean Square Error reference

Tags: references, rms, history

Does anyone know the first author (a reference) using RMSE as a criterion to evaluate the performance of a model?

Comment: It would surely have occurred before the year 1800.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the exact purpose of the usage of the reference since it depends on the field of study. however the usage of RMSE where the interpretation is root mean-square error or in some cases root mean-square difference is simultaneously used. Personally i prefer to use it as difference, since any data can be subject to some uncertainties even if it is measured with high precession. The refrence and further details about my statement can be verified through the links given 
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/257381233_Selection_of_Performance_Metrics_for_Global_Soil_Moisture_Products[RMSE][1]
Or https://gmao.gsfc.nasa.gov/pubs/docs/Entekhabi406.pdf

Again the the reference depends on the usage and field of study. That is just my own opinion and does mean to be correct. The readers and writer both should pick what is best for his/her study